# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ".\bin\catalina.bat" - CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat

I am getting the following error when attempting to begin a Tomcat process using Java.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ".\bin\catalina.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\chiranga93\Documents\GitHub\product
-as\integration-tests\target\wso2as-6.0.0-SNAPSHOT"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.wso2.appserver.test.integration.TestSuiteListener.startPlatformDependApplicationServer(TestSuiteListener.
java:152)
```

The code segment used for this is as follows:

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.directory(appserverHome);
        processBuilder.environment().put("JAVA_OPTS", jacocoArg);

        if (os.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
            log.info("Starting server as a " + os + " process");
            return applicationServerProcess = processBuilder.command("\\bin\\catalina.bat", "run").start();
        } else {
            log.info("Starting server as a " + os + " process");
            return applicationServerProcess = processBuilder.command("./bin/catalina.sh", "run").start();
        }
```

The `CATALINA_HOME\bin\catalina.bat` file exists in the bin folder. But it specifies that the particular file is not there.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `processBuilder.directory(File)` only sets the working directory for the created process but is not used for the command string itself.

Therefore make the command an absolute path, e.g.

```
if (os.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
    String catalinaPath = new File(appserverHome, "bin\\catalina.bat").getAbsolutePath();
    return applicationServerProcess = processBuilder.command(catalinaPath, "run").start();
} ...
```